# Jsoup Wont Extract Text

Tags: java, jsoup, element

I cannot extract the text from the css path what am i doing wrong?

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Document doc;

    // need http protocol
    doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=example").get();
    Elements links = doc.select("#uid_0 > div._OKe > ol > li:nth-child(2) > div > div.kno-ecr-pt.kno-fb-ctx");
    System.out.println("text : " + links.text());

    }
}
```

The output should be EXAMPLE

Thanks.

Comment: Log cat please/ what did it print out?

Comment: nothing just the word Test

Comment: Did you check to see if it parsed at all?

Comment: I tried printing it to the screen but nothing will come up

Comment: Change User Agent to something a desktop browser would use. BTW, scraping is against googles Terms Of Service.

Comment: Which element are you looking for? I am able to get the page source but I dont know which element you are looking for. I dont see any `kno-ecr-pt.kno-fb-ctx` in the page source.

Comment: @LittlePanda #uid_0 > div._OKe > ol > li:nth-child(2) > div > div.kno-ecr-pt.kno-fb-ctx 
is the css path

Comment: @JonasCz i was just using it as an example its for work

Answer (score 0):

This can get you the source code properly.

```
Document doc = Jsoup
.connect("your url")
.userAgent("Mozilla")
.timeout(5000)
.get();

Elements links = doc.select("your css path");
```